# Styling of registration form with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, reactjs

How about applying styles to my webapp I am creating(a simple jsp registration page for now). The page is cluttered with no style and looks dull.

I heard about some cool bootstraps which will help in styling(Such as angularjs, react js for webapps)and also what it does like mvc patterns(angular) and virtual dom(react) so please don't worry me about those details.

For now I just want to finish styling to my registration page. So please thrown in ideas or suggestion if anyone have worked with it

Below is my sample form where users should register:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/Registratonvalidation.js"></script>
            <title>Registration Form</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
            First name:<input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/>
            Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" /><br/>
            Gender: Male<input type="radio" name="male" /> Female<input type="radio" name="female" /><br/>
            Mobile:<input type="tel" name="mobile" /><br/>
            Email:<input type="email" name="email" /><br/>
            Address:<textarea name="address"></textarea><br/>
            Street:<input type="text" name="street" /><br/>
            Area:<input type="text" name="area" /><br/>

            City:<select>
                <option value="hyderabad">hyderabad</option>
                <option value="secunderabad">secunderabad</option>
                <option value="delhi">delhi</option>
                <option value="mumbai">mumbai</option>
            </select>

            State: <input type="text" name="state" /><br/>
            Country: <input type="text" name="country" /><br/>
            Pin: <input type="text" name="pin" /><br/>
            <br/>
            <h3>please type a username and password</h3>

            Username:<input type="text" name="uname" /><br/>
            Password:<input type="password" name="pwd" /><br/>
            Confirm Password:<input type="password" name="pwd2" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at CSS frameworks, like: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms or http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html

Comment: I have no idea except css

Comment: Here is a more curated list: http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html?v=2.0